# R BNlearn's how does SHD function work?

Tags: r, bayesian-networks

Let's get example and description from documentation

```
data(learning.test)
e1 = model2network("[A][B][C|A:B][D|B][E|C][F|A:E]")
e2 = model2network("[A][B][C|A:B][D|B][E|C:F][F|A]")
```

e1 graph is:

[e1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtsEr.png)

And e2 graph is:

[e2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzMXg.png)

function `shd(...)` should return the count of differences (in direction, existence or not existence of some arc) between these graphs. But it returns 2 and says that e2 contains A-F arc, but it contains only A->F arc. Why?

```
> shd(e2, e1, debug = TRUE)
* arcs between A and F do not match.
  > the learned network contains A - F.
  > the true network contains A -> F.
* arcs between E and F do not match.
  > the learned network contains F -> E.
  > the true network contains E -> F.

[1] 2
```

Comment: According to the help, `?shd`, under the notes section, the measure is defined on the cpdag's rather than the graph itself.  Looking at `plot(cpdag(e2))` the original edge from A->F is coerced to undirected, as the graphs with either edge, A->F, or F->A are indistinguishable (there are in the same equivalence class) . This is not true of `plot(cpdag(e1))` due to the converging edge on `A`.